# Discord.js Reaction collector failing if no user reacts with first reaction. Cannot read property 'count' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've set up a pretty basic reaction collector for discord.js - i've got 2 emojis that get used to react to a message. However if users only react with downVote (not upvote, the system errors):

```
D:\tzobot\commands\poll.js:102
                if (reacts.get(downVote).count == reacts.get(upVote).count) { draw = true; }
                                                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
    at ReactionCollector.<anonymous> (D:\tzobot\commands\poll.js:102:55)
    at ReactionCollector.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at ReactionCollector.stop (D:\tzobot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:149:10)
    at D:\tzobot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\Collector.js:72:73
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\tzobot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:436:7)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

This doesn't occur if the opposite happens (users react with upvote not downvote). 
Relevant code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const downVote = "";
const upVote = "";

//irrelevantcode here setting properties such as duration etc.

const mesEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle(`Poll: ${pollQuestion}`)
            //.setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
            .setAuthor(`${message.author.username}`, `${message.author.avatarURL}`, 'https://discord.js.org')
            .setDescription('Reply with  or  to give your opinion.')

        sendmes(message, mesEmbed);


    },

};
async function sendmes(message, mesEmbed) {
    let msg = await message.reply(mesEmbed);
    await msg.react(upVote);
    await msg.react(downVote);
    await startTimer(msg);



}
async function startTimer(mes) {
    let filter = (reaction) => reaction.emoji.name == upVote || reaction.emoji.name == downVote;

    const collector = mes.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: pollDuration });
    collector.on('end', collected => {
        console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
        if (collected.size == 0) return mes.reply(`Poll: "${pollQuestion}" has now finished. The result is a tie with no votes.`); 
        var draw = Boolean(false);
        var winner = null;
        var loser = null;
        var reacts = collected;
        console.log(reacts);




        if (reacts.get(downVote).count == reacts.get(upVote).count) { draw = true; }
        else if (reacts.get(upVote).count > reacts.get(downVote).count) { winner = (upVote), loser = (downVote) }
        else { winner = (downVote), loser = (upVote) }
        //Check it wasn't a draw
        if (draw == false) return mes.reply(`Poll: "${pollQuestion}" has now finished. The final decision is: ${winner} with ${reacts.get(winner).count} votes.  ${loser} recieved ${reacts.get(loser).count} votes.`);
        //Return draw message if it was
        else return mes.reply(`Poll: "${pollQuestion}" has now finished. The result is a tie with ${reacts.get(upVote).count} votes each.`);

    });
```

How can I prevent/handle the current error I am receiving better. I've tried setting downvote.count to 0 if it is null however this doesn't resolve it. It is very confusing how this only occurs when upvote isnt reacted but not visa-versa.

if (reacts.get(downVote).count == null) reacts.get(downVote).count = 0;

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by having the bot react after the timer was intialized: 

  
 `await startTimer(msg);
await msg.react(upVote);
await msg.react(downVote);`

However i'd still like to know why the issue occurred and how i can improve this to prevent similar issues occurring.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain as to why it doesn't fail when users react with upvote only, I would expect it to fail in both scenarios.  The reason it fails is because .get() returns undefined when nothing is available to get, and undefined does not have a count property.  You just have to guard against such an outcome.

```
let uv = reacts.get(upVote);
let dv = reacts.get(downVote);
if (!uv && !dv) { 
    draw = true; // Both were undefined, nobody voted.
} else if (uv && dv && dv.count == uv.count) {
    draw = true; // Neither was undefined and both had the same value.
}
```

Compact version

```
let uv = reacts.get(upVote);
let dv = reacts.get(downVote);
let draw = (!uv && !dv) || (uv && dv && dv.count == uv.count);
```